# React component this.props is always empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux, react-router, react-router-component

I've followed a [couple](http://rackt.github.io/react-router/#Router%20Overview) of [examples](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/examples/query-params/app.js) in an attempt to get access to a parameter from a Route in the React component that handles it. However the result of `console.log` on `this.props` from inside the `render` or `componentDidMount` is always `{}` when I'd expect it to contain the `gameId` from the `gamesView` route.

`client.js` which starts the Router:

```
// HTML5 History API fix for local 
if (config.environment === 'dev') {
    var router = Router.create({ routes: routes });
} else {
    var router = Router.create({ routes: routes, location: Router.HistoryLocation });
}

router.run(function(Handler) {
    React.render(
        <Handler />,
        document.getElementById('app')
    );
});
```

`routes.js` with some routes removed for simplicity:

```
var routes = (
    <Route name='home' path='/' handler={app}>
        <DefaultRoute handler={home} location="/" />
        <Route name='gamesView' path='/games/:gameId' handler={gamesView} />
    </Route>
);

module.exports = routes;
```

...and `app.js` which wraps the other routes, I've tried it both with and without `{...this.props}` in the `RouteHandler`. If I `console.log(this.props)` from inside the `render` function here is also returns `{}`:

```
var App = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className='container'>
                <div className='row'>
                    <RouteHandler {...this.props} />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = App;
```

Finally the `gamesView` React component that I expect to see the props object. Here `this.props` is also `{}` and the following results in the error `TypeError: $__0 is undefined     var $__0=    this.props.params,gameId=$__0.gameId;`:

```
var GamesView = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var { gameId } = this.props.params;

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Game Name</h1>
                <p>{gameId}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = GamesView;
```

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: shouldn't it be



`<RouteHandler prop1={this.props.prop1} prop2={this.props.prop1} />`

Comment: @pkurek I believe I should be able to use the [spread operator](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html) and not have to name props explicitly in the RouteHandler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After [discussing on the React Router (RR) Github](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/1422) it turned out this was due to me using an older version of RR (v0.11.6).

Looking at the [example in the docs for that release](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/v0.11.6/examples/query-params/app.js) it showed that I needed to use a `Router.State` mixin and then get the expected param via `var gameId = this.getParams().gameId;`.

Without upgrading RR the working version of my original example for `GamesView` becomes:

```
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router');
var { Route, RouteHandler, Link } = Router;

var GamesView = React.createClass({

    mixins: [ Router.State ],

    render: function() {
        var gameId = this.getParams().gameId;

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Game Name</h1>
                <p>{gameId}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = GamesView;
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't see those params *until* you are at the component defined in your router. `App` won't know anything about them. If you put the `console.log(this.props.params)` in your `gamesView` component, however, you should see them.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either @Hal, I'd tried previously and have edited my original example above to show what happens when I try and access `this.props` from the component that handles that route.